# How to install boost wave driver program

Tags: c++, boost

According to the boost wave documentation there is a binary `wave` (the wave driver executable) associated with it.

I did `brew install boost` on macOS, and I do get boost wave library files, but I cannot find the `wave` binary. It is very hard to find online how I can get this binary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd download the tarball (https://www.boost.org/users/download/), extract it and then optionally follow build instructions.

After that move into `libs/wave/tool/build` directory and build there using `b2` as well.

Simple demo on a blank debian-like:

```
apt update && apt install -y build-essential curl 
curl -L https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.82.0/source/boost_1_82_0.tar.gz | tar -xz
cd boost_1_82_0
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=wave,program_options  cxxflags=-DBOOST_WAVE_SUPPORT_HAS_INCLUDE=0
./b2 libs/wave/tool/build/ cxxflags=-DBOOST_WAVE_SUPPORT_HAS_INCLUDE=0
bin.v2/libs/wave/tool/build/gcc-11/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/wavetool-on/wave
```

[image]